# Import error on django models.py

Tags: python, django

I wrote this funcion on a utils.py located on the app direcroty:

```
from bm.bmApp.models import Client

def get_client(user):
    try:
        client = Client.objects.get(username=user.username)
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        print "User Does not Exist"
        return None
    else:       
        return client

def to_safe_uppercase(string):
    if string is None:
        return ''
    return string.upper()
```

Then when i use the function to_safe_uppercase on my models.py file, by importing it in this way:

```
from bm.bmApp.utils import to_safe_uppercase
```

I got the python error:

```
     from bm.bmApp.utils import to_safe_uppercase
ImportError: cannot import name to_safe_uppercase
```

I got the solution for this problem when i change the import statement for:

```
from bm.bmApp.utils import *
```

But i can't understand why is this, why when i import the specific function i got the error?

Comment: This should not happen. I suspect there is something else going on.

Comment: unfortunately, django by default catches ImportErrors and replaces them with this errormessage. try to patch django, so that it gives you the traceback, this should point to the problem. I suspect cyclic imports or something like that.

Comment: @ch3ka patching django isn't a great idea... also he is getting the python traceback already. He's pasted part of it in the question

Comment: @Jiaaro not for production use, of course. And I don't think that's the full traceback, as said, django used to hide it (not sure it that's true for recent versions, though) But Mark spotted the Problem already anyways: as I suspected, it's a circular import.

Answer (score 12):

You are doing what is known as a Circular import.

models.py:

```
from bm.bmApp.utils import to_safe_uppercase
```

utils.py:

```
from bm.bmApp.models import Client
```

Now when you do `import bm.bmApp.models` The interpreter does the following:

1. `models.py - Line 1`: try to import `bm.bmApp.utils`
2. `utils.py - Line 1`: try to import `bm.bmApp.models`
3. `models.py - Line 1`: try to import `bm.bmApp.utils`
4. `utils.py - Line 1`: try to import `bm.bmApp.models`
5. ...

The easiest solution is to move the import inside the function:

utils.py:

```
def get_client(user):
    from bm.bmApp.models import Client
    try:
        client = Client.objects.get(username=user.username)
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        print "User Does not Exist"
        return None
    else:       
        return client

def to_safe_uppercase(string):
    if string is None:
        return ''
    return string.upper()
```

Answer (score 8):

You are creating a circular import.

```
utils.py
from bm.bmApp.models import Client
# Rest of the file...

models.py
from bm.bmApp.utils import to_safe_uppercase
# Rest of the file...
```

I would suggest your refactor your code so that you don't have a circular dependency (i.e. utils should not need to import models.py or vice versa).

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module

Comment: Thanks. You should consider adding something about it in your answer,  it's part of the OP's question. :)

Comment: I've checking the link above, and it seems this get this problem:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can explain the Import error, but I have three ideas. First, your function needs tweaking. You've used a reserved word 'string' as an argument. Consider renaming.

Second, what happens if you invoke ./manage.py shell, and do the import by hand. Does it give you any different?

Third, try deleting your pyc files to force django to recompile python code (this one is a very long shot...but worth eliminating)